# Absolute position element in bootstrap3 - force width to be the same as container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

tl;dr - how do I get the results div to be the same width as the input here: http://plnkr.co/edit/44hVxWVZzYY32Fx6dqpp?p=preview

Given the following html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input style="width:100%" />
      <div class="results">
        <ul id="search-list">
          <li>Result1</li>
          <li class="selected">Result2</li>
          <li>Result3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.results {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.9);
  width: 100%;
}

#search-list li {
  font-size: 130%;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

The results div is wider than the input:

[image]

I would like the results to be the exact width as the input. I can achieve this by removing the absolute positioning from the `.results` element. But, I need the results to appear atop any subsequent content. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Your plnkr demo seems to be working for me. Did you manage to fix it yourself?

Comment: yeah, oops .. new to plnkr .. - reverted to broken version. *Best* way to achieve what I'm trying to do is still up for debate.

Comment: I would first remove inline style and use the class "form-control" on the input, which is 100% width. That is it.

Comment: This fixed it: http://plnkr.co/edit/fUDTajSEzgyDgDNwUoW9?p=preview -- no width on absolute, just put left:15px and right:15px; then the gutter is covered. Use the form-control class too, but I guess it's optional

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple:

```
.results {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left:15px;
  right:15px;
}
```

Get to know the Bootstrap grid and you'll understand that there's 15px on either side of every col-*- class on the vanilla download.

Answer (score 0):

One, somewhat hacky seeming way would be to move the background to the `li` and then use padding on the container. Then, have to be more specific with the `.selected` rule.

http://plnkr.co/edit/alLfxA?p=preview

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.results {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#search-list li {
  font-size: 130%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.9);

}

#search-list li.selected {
  background: yellow;
}
```